# Tomcat 8 Connection has been abandoned

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, connection-pooling, transactionmanager

First time posting question. Thanks all!

The issue I have is been around for a while and we couldn't find a solution for that. In short, application build using Java 8, Spring, Hibernate, PostgreSQL, JSF (PrimeFaces here), Webflow.
The problem related to Connection being closed, but it seems that application still uses it, so next time some logic borrows the same connection it just "stumbles" on it, and throws exception:

```
 Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)

Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connection has already been closed.
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ProxyConnection.invoke(ProxyConnection.java:117)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.JdbcInterceptor.invoke(JdbcInterceptor.java:108)
```

Application could work for couple days without problems, until something happens, where it gets Connection abandoned warning from tomcat. From there is just won't work fine, and many process would get that closed connection and will fail measurably, because connection is already closed:

```
 WARNING [Tomcat JDBC Pool Cleaner[1989780873:1502425160484]] org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.abandon Connection has been abandoned PooledConnection[org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@234be71f]:java.lang.Exception
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.getThreadDump(ConnectionPool.java:1093)
```

Our team spend hours and hours on that issue, searching in the web, and consulting fellow developers, and in the beginning it was all come down to trying to tweak Tomcat server.xml, but without any success. It could run fine for another days, and then fail with same problem, where server will become inconsistent, so the only thing to do is restart it. The interceptors we added didn't help, and only there as part of trying to solve problem.

Only later we could reliably replicate the issue, and the issue was pretty interesting on its own. So, Tomcat would throw Abandoned Connection (close it) when any Exception thrown within transaction, custom or regular Java, such as if there is NoResultException or some MyCustomException based on assertion is thrown; 60 seconds later (removeAbandonedTimeout) Tomcat will display Warning Message and connection will be closed. But the problem that logic still refers to it, and more connections closed down the line, more things breaks while performing business logic.

There are two dataSources configured in server.xml (one for business logic, another for Jobs) as follows:

```
<Resource auth="Container" driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
initialSize="5"
jdbcInterceptors=
"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState; 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer; 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReportJmx (threshold=10000)"
logAbandoned="true" 
maxActive="30" 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
minIdle="5" 
name="jdbc/my-app-db"
password=""
removeAbandoned="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnReturn="false" 
testWhileIdle="true"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
url="jdbc:postgresql://mydb.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/mydb_db" 
username=""
validationInterval="30000" 
validationQuery="SELECT 1" />

<Resource auth="Container" 
driverClassName="org.postgresql.Driver"
factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory" 
initialSize="5"
jdbcInterceptors=
"org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState; 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer; 
org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.SlowQueryReportJmx (threshold=10000)"
logAbandoned="true" 
maxActive="30" 
minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
minIdle="5" 
name="jdbc/my-app-db-for-jobs" 
password=""
removeAbandoned="true" 
removeAbandonedTimeout="60" 
testOnBorrow="true"
testOnReturn="false" 
testWhileIdle="true"
timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="5000" 
type="javax.sql.DataSource"
url="jdbc:postgresql://mydb.rds.amazonaws.com:5432/myapp_db" 
username=""
validationInterval="30000" 
validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
```

And xml configuration:

```
 <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="acme"></property>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>
```

and POM.xml with some dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is the piece of the code that could fail, but really anything that has a transaction, or anything that query DB could stumble upon closed Pool Conection:

```
 PromoCode promoCodeEntity = null;
    try {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = (JpaTransactionManager) ApplicationContextProvider
                .getApplicationContext().getBean("transactionManager");
        TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
        TransactionStatus status = transactionManager.getTransaction(def);

        String jpql = "select p from PromoCode p where p.code = :code";
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql).setParameter("code", promoCode);
        promoCodeEntity = (PromoCode) query.getSingleResult();

        if (promoCodeEntity.getQuantyOfUses() >= promoCodeEntity.getTotalOfUses()) {
            MyCustomException myCustomException = new MyCustomException("This promo code is not valid: [" + promoCode + "]");
            MyCustomException.setCode("PROMO_CODE");
            throw myCustomException;
        }

        if (!promoCodeEntity.getActive() || promoCodeEntity.getFinish()) {
            MyCustomException myCustomException = new MyCustomException("This promo code is not valid: [" + promoCode + "]");
            myCustomException.setCode("PROMO_CODE");
            throw myCustomException;
        }

        if (!(promoCodeEntity.getStartDateValid().before(new Date())
                && promoCodeEntity.getEndDateValid().after(new Date()))) {
            MyCustomException myCustomException = new MyCustomException("This promo code is expired: [" + promoCode + "]");
            myCustomException.setCode("PROMO_CODE");
            throw myCustomException;
        }
        promoCodeEntity.setQuantyOfUses(promoCodeEntity.getQuantyOfUses() + 1);
        transactionManager.commit(status);
    } catch (NoResultException e) {
        MyCustomException myCustomException = new MyCustomException("Promo code not found: [" + promoCode + "]");
        myCustomException.setCode("PROMO_CODE");
        throw myCustomException;
    }
```

Has anyone encounter such problem, or where should I look further? We made some drivers updates (such as postgres jdbc), also currently evaluating c3p0 Pool, to see if this is Tomcat Pool bugs related. But really will be nice to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Were you able to solve the issue? If yes, please share how?

Comment: Please see the response below. It may not be related to your particular issue, but who knows. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured the problem out after many hours of debugging and other things.

I should have post some code snipped along with original question, which could have help other Stackoverflow users to understand the issue correctly.

The solution to the problem was that we were using TransactionManager as instantiated object and were catching exception as it happens

```
JpaTransactionManager txManager = (JpaTransactionManager) context.getBean("transactionManager");
    TransactionDefinition def = new DefaultTransactionDefinition();
    TransactionStatus status = txManager.getTransaction(def);
    try {
        String jpql = "query";
        Query query = em.createQuery(jpql).setParameter("id", id);
        User singleResult = (User) query.getSingleResult();
        singleResult.setActive(false);
        this.em.merge(singleResult);
        this.em.flush();
        txManager.commit(status);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("lockUser(Long)", e);
        throw e;
    }
}
```

however in catch block after we never rolled back transaction as exception occurred, so Tomcat Pool manager basically were closing down connection as it was abandoned.

adding this in catch block solved that particular problem:

```
txManager.rollback(status);
```

Or another solution for us was using Spring @Transactional annotation and let spring handle rolling back transactions on error.

Thanks all for looking at this issue though!

Answer (score 0):

you nee to use `connectionTimeout` into your `dataSources` property. right now you are using default timeout, after timeout it forces to session to close. so you can try to add below code into  `dataSources` property :

```
        connectionTimeout="300000"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try altering your c3p0 properties. unreturnedConnectionTimeout handles hanging connections. If you have some query taking too much time, connection can timed out leaving a db connection hanging. You have limited connections, So if this process repeats, can exhaust you connections. 
testConnectionOnCheckout checks whether connection is closed, if not then close it.

```
c3p0.unreturnedConnectionTimeout=2000
c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout=true
```

Comment: Thanks for response. The issue is not related to queries taking too long, it could, but not right now. We currently made a setup with HikariCP Pool, but problem didn't go away it looks. Connections may be exhausted, but due to other than query timeout reason.